# How can I make a page for post formats (specifically quotes) in wordpress 3.5

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create the ability for the end user to add quotes (testimonials) as posts. So far, so good. I have enabled the 'quote' post-format in my theme. So the ability exists to enter said testimonials, and I have even figured out how to show some random quotes in the sidebar. The next obvious step is to have a "testimonials" page, where all of the quotes are archived, over time. It needs the ability to be a page, which means that the client can alter the text in the page, and it can be linked to, in menus and on pages. Following the opening (editable) text, would be a list of the quotes, like an archive page, except that the entire quote would be on the page. For that reason, it would at some point, have to become paged. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I just posted it there. Should I still leave it here?

Comment: @Rob: No, please delete this one.